# After updated ios 6.0, when back to foreground the frame of view has changed

Tags: ios

I set the view's frame so that view can move up when clicking on the textfield,and i enter the home button to go to the background,but when I come back to the foreground, the keyboard is also shown but the view's frame has reset.Here are the 3 pics. This occurs in ios 6 but never occurs in ios 5 and earlier. Who knows why this come about and how to deal with it.Sorry I can not post a image to show u.

Comment: Please, add the images. Is it possible your textfield stops being first responder and you don't handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Cant find any images here. But I faced the same issue and fixed it like so. This is not a great fix. But does the job. Let me know if it helps.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```